# Javascript: Replace all occurences of ' a ' in a string with ' b ' with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string like 'a b b b a' and want to replace every 'b' in that string that has a whitespace before and after the character with a different character. How could I do that with a regex? My idea was this:

```
'x a y a x'.replace(new RegExp(' a ', 'g'), ' b '); // is: x b y b x, should: x b y b x (correct)
'x a a a x'.replace(new RegExp(' a ', 'g'), ' b '); // is: x b a b x, should: x b b b x (wrong)
'x aa x'.replace(new RegExp(' a ', 'g'), ' b '); // is: x aa x, should: x aa x (correct)
```

But that regex is only working if there is not more than 1 occurence of the character next to another occurence of the character. How could I write the regex to get the right behaviour?

Comment: `a+` instead of only `a`

Comment: Regex is reading each character waiting to get ' a ' when it reaches the first one like so: 'x[ a ]a a x' it replaces it and continues on to the next bit 'a a x'. It skips the next 'a' since it doesn't have a space before it, ignoring that 'a'. Thats why you get 'x b a b x'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use  a lookahead after " a" to match overlapping substrings:

```
/ a(?= )/g
```

Or, to match any whitespace, replace spaces with `\s`.

The [**lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), being a [**zero-width assertion**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#stand_their_ground), does not consume the text, so the space after " a" will be available for the next match (the first space in the pattern is part of the consuming pattern).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqSXHg/1)

```js
var regex = / a(?= )/g;
var strs = ['x a y a x', 'x a a a x', 'x aa x'];
for (var str of strs) {
 console.log(str,' => ', str.replace(regex, " b"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As your matches are overlapping, you can use zero width assertion i.e a positive lookahead based regex:

```
str = str.replace(/( )a(?= )/g, "\1b");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fKlXRB/1)

- `( )a` will match a space before `a` and capture it in group #1 followed by `a`
- `(?= )` will assert presence of a space after `a` but won't consume it in the match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp with `g` flag with the `replace` method. Try this

```
var mystring = "this is a a a a a a test"
mystring.replace(/ a /g , "b");
```